# What does "configure the gem in the config block of config/environment.rb" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing my first Rails app. The app uses a lot of enumerations, so I'd like to include [this gem](https://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute) that makes it easier to work with them.

I'm stumped by the [installation instructions](https://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute#setup), though, which say

> [...] For a rails application configure the gem in the config block of
>   the `config/environment.rb` file
>
> ```
> config.gem "enumerated_attribute"
> ```

In my `config/environment.rb` I don't see anything that looks like a "config block".

`config/environment.rb`:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Webtet::Application.initialize!
```

So what does the author mean when he writes "configure the gem in the config block"?

Does he just want me to include this line in `config/environment.rb`

```
config.gem "enumerated_attribute"
```

?

Comment: Maybe he means the `config/application.rb`? Although can't you just check and see if sticking it in the `config/environment.rb` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this setup instruction was written for rails 2 application. If this gem works with rails 3 you just should add `gem 'enumerated_attribute'` to your Gemfile. Also you can try to use https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize gem (it works with rails 3 and has SimpleForm, Formtastic support and other awesome features)

Comment: Beat me by 30 sec so I deleted my answer :) Looking at the code in enumerated_attributes, I can't say I have much faith in the future of that code base. It's not written using Ruby coding standards, which is always a red flag for me. Enumerize looks like a good replacement, or my own [ClassyEnum](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum) if you think you could benefit from objects and polymorphism.

Comment: Cool -- thanks guys. :)  I'll have a look at Enumerize and ClassyEnum.